# Using multiple semicolons?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons

First of all, apologies if this has already been asked. I've done some searching however have not been able to find a like topic.

My question is pretty straight forward.

How, *if possible* can I use multiple semicolons in one sentence? I'm quite uncertain whether this is some sort of literature taboo, since I've never really come across more than one semicolon used in a single sentence.

Some guidence would be very much appreciated (:

Comment: The *very first* example sentence in [the Wikipedia article on semicolons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#Usage) has several of them.

Comment: Welcome to the site by the way!

Comment: Other than the 'super-serial-comma' usage Reg points out, there are probably not too many sensible examples. The usual usage is to weld together two fairly-closely-semantically-connected sentences. A series of three would probably be better punctuated using coordinators or separate sentences.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I guess it was my mistake to not include the cases where I know you can use multiple semicolons, such as when listing things.

Comment: To conclude, I'll heed to what Edwin said. Also, thanks to @Cerberus